# python OR-tools, how to make certain numbers in a 2D-array be specific numbers

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I have a 2D list called list_of_numbers where each list in the list has 1 or-tools model int variable inside of it where the numbers can be from 0 to 10. I have another 2D list called list_of_positions and i need to write constraints based on the list of positions make the numbers in the list of numbers be specific numbers. I apologize if this gets a little confusing. In the example below list_of_positions equals     [[1],[2],[0,3],[]]. This list means that the number 0 has to be at either index 1 in the list_of_numbers, and the number 1 has to be at index 2 in the list_of_numbers, the number 2 has to be at index 0 and 3 and because the last one in the list of position is blank that means that the number 3 cannot be in any position in the list_of_numbers. so the list_of_numbers would end up being [[2],[0],[1],[2]]

This is the code that i have

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

#prints the solution at the end
def print_solution(list_of_numbers, solver):
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_numbers)):
        for j in range(0, 1):
            print(f'{solver.Value(list_of_numbers[i][j]):2} ', end = '')

        print()

#creates a list of 4 int variables that can be from 0 to 10
list_of_numbers = []
for i in range(0, 4):
    number = []
    for j in range(0, 1):
        number.append(model.NewIntVar(0, 10, f'list_of_numbers{i}_{j}'))
    list_of_numbers.append(number)

list_of_positions =  [[1],[2],[0,3],[]]

#this is where i tried writing a constraint but im terrible with or-tools and i know this is way off
####################################
for i in range(0,len(list_of_positions)):
    for j in range(0,len(list_of_positions[i])):
        model.Add(list_of_numbers[i] == list_of_positions[i][j])
#####################################

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status in [cp_model.OPTIMAL, cp_model.FEASIBLE]:
    print_solution(list_of_numbers, solver)
else:
    print('unsat')
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way to do this. This produces the output [2, 0, 1, 2].

```
# pos[idx]: numbers which can occupy position idx
pos = [[] for _ in range(len(list_of_numbers))]  

for num, available_idx in enumerate(list_of_positions):
    if available_idx:
        for idx in available_idx:
            pos[idx].append(num)

for i, var in enumerate(list_of_numbers):
    domain = cp_model.Domain.FromValues(pos[i])
    model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(var[0], domain)
```